# Material Design in RecyclerView issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textinputlayout

I'm using Material Design, MVVM, Room, two-way data binding in my project. I'm making the view expand and collapse i.e, visible and gone in recycler view which contains material design TextInputLayout, and if I expanding the loaded views and if the textbox is loaded then there is a black spot seen over the label part for a fraction of second and this issue is only seen on first-time after item load and expanding that item. Don't know how to fix this issue! please help me solve this issue as I'm trying for the past few days

I have attached a GIF showing the issue

[Black Spot appears on label part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSbYk.gif)

Comment: It's likely you are having time to load datas from server. If not than it would be better if you add some source code of adapter......

Comment: okay, I will upload my source code

Comment: this is an adapter source code which you asked for [link](https://www.codepile.net/pile/VJ4MqQly)_italic_